# Creating a form in Django not based on model causes error

Tags: python, django

I created a form in Django as follows:

```
class advancedsearch(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ChoiceField (label="choices", choices = ("1", "2", "3"), required= False)
```

Now I'm trying to use this in a view as follows:

```
def advancedsearch(request):
    # if request.method == "POST":
    #   search = advancedsearch(request.POST, request.FILES)
    #   if search.is_valid():
    #       return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("view.designs")) #    UPDATE REDIRECT
    #   else:
    #       print "FORM IS NOT VALID"
    #     # GET request
    # else:
    #   search = advancedsearch()
    #   return render_to_response("advancedsearch.html", {
    #       "search": search,
    #       }, context_instance=RequestContext(request,{}))
    # # generic case
    search = advancedsearch()
    return render_to_response("advancedsearch.html", {
        "search": search,
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request, {}))
```

The error I am getting is `advancedsearch() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)`

I didn't think I needed to pass an argument to the function -- but it looks like I do...What should I be passing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search = advancedsearch()` is called the view method `advancedsearch()` rather than the form

You can do something like this:

```
class AdvancedSearchForm(forms.Form):
    choices = forms.ChoiceField (label="choices", choices = ((1, 1),(2, 2),(2, 3)), required= False)
```

and in the view:

```
search = AdvancedSearchForm()
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks but now I'm getting the error: `need more than 1 value to unpack` when I try to use it in my template as `{{search.choices}}` ... is this related?

Answer (score 1):

You gave the same name to the form and the view. So the view is calling itself recursively without anything to stop it.

The form does not need an argument, but because the view has the same name has the model, Python thinks you want to call the view, which needs an argument.

You should either rename your model or your view.